# Creating new database using UniDAC

Tags: database, delphi, unidac

I have been struggling with a function that allows users to create a new db for my apps
It has to be a universal function as some use MS Access, some SQLite and others MySQL

I have spend hours looking in the supplied demo without finding anything of use to me

What I want is to be able to do is to create a new db given the parameters for: Provider, Server, Port, User, Password, DB name (or filename)

I have the following function for creating MS Access
But it doesn't do the trick.

```
Calling it by   SQLConfigDataSource(0, 1, 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)','CREATE_DB="' + DatabaseName + '"')

Function SQLConfigDataSource(hwndParent: Integer; fRequest: Integer;
  lpszDriverString: string; lpszAttributes: string): Integer; stdcall;
var
  func : TSQLConfigDataSource;
  ODBCHModule: HMODULE;
begin
  ODBCHModule := LoadLibrary('odbccp32.dll');
  if ODBCHModule = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  func :=  GetProcAddress(ODBCHModule,PChar('SQLConfigDataSource'));
  if @func = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Error Getting adress for SQLConfigDataSource' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

  Result := func(hwndParent, fRequest, lpszDriverString, lpszAttributes);
  FreeLibrary(ODBCHModule);
end;
```

Comment: I use Delphi XE and UniDac 4.1.5
(have been around since version 2 so basics are in place)

Comment: Did you delve into `UniDacDemo` source code? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes I have looked in the demo sourcecode and there is not a solution there

Comment: I remember of managing to have UniDacDemo works with MysQL, PostgreSQL and Firebird: Just one click away.

Comment: not sure if you can create a database for MS Access, but I'm sure you can for SQLite, Postgres and MySQL, I've done it by setting the schema to UniScript's SQL property and calling .Execute

Answer (score 1):

1. SQLite - just open a database. If it does not exist then it will be created.
2. MySQL - you need to connect with a server. Then execute `CREATE DATABASE <name>` command.
3. Microsoft Access - this depends on the components you are using. I does not know about UniDAC. But using ODBC execute `SQLConfigDataSource(0, ODBC_ADD_DSN, '<driver name>', 'CREATE_DB=<db path>')`.

Comment: I have tried the SQLConfigDataSource method but I can't get it working
At first I thought that it might be that there wasn't a trusted location where I tried to create the db, but that wasn't the case.
So I don't know what the problem can be.

Comment: 1) You should also use SQLInstallerError to get the error text. 2) If you are using Unicode Delphi, then use SQLConfigDataSourceW. If non-Unicode, then SQLConfigDataSource.

Comment: You don't happen to have a sample code that demonstrates this?